# Table shows headers in a column not as a row

Tags: php, css, formatting, css-tables

I'm a little puzzled with this one. I've got my code to display how ever it will not display it in the format I wish, I want it to be:

```
section    serial    bike    time
info1      info2     info3   info4
info1      info2     info3   info4
info1      info2     info3   info4
info1      info2     info3   info4
```

and so on..

however my code is displayed as:

```
section
serial
bike
time

info1    info1    info1    info1
info2    info2    info2    info2
```

etc

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="table" style="width:100%;" > 
      <?php

           # table 1

            print '<div class="thead">'; #thead

                   print '      <div class="th"><div class="spaced"></div>';
               print 'Section';
               print '      </div>';

               print '      <div class="th"><div class="spaced"></div>';    
               print 'Serial';
               print '      </div>';

               print '      <div class="th"><div class="spaced"></div>';    
               print 'Bike';
               print '      </div>';

               print '      <div class="th"><div class="spaced"></div>';    
               print 'Time';
               print '      </div>';
          print '</div>'; #thead  


        print '<div class="tbody">';  #tbody
        for ($i=1;$i<=$num_rows;$i++) 
        {
           print '<div class="tr">';
             for ($x=1;$x<=2;$x++)
             {

               if ($x == 1)
                   $row_pos = $i;
               else
                   $row_pos = $num_stations - $i;

               print '<div class="td">';
               print '<div class="table">';
               print '   <div class="tr"  format me        >';    
               print '      <div class="td"><div class="spaced"></div>';     
               print $station_detail[$row_pos]['station_name'];
               print '      </div>';
               print '      <div class="td"><div class="spaced"></div>';    
               print $station_detail[$row_pos]['station_name'];;
               print '      </div>';
               print '      <div class="td"><div class="spaced"></div>';
               print $station_detail[$row_pos]['station_name'];
               print '      </div>';
               print '      <div class="td"><div class="spaced"></div>';
               print $station_detail[$row_pos]['station_name'];
               print '      </div>';
               print '   </div></div>';
             }

           print '</div>'; #tr
           print '</div>'; #tbody
        }
     ?>

        </div>
  </div><!-- close table -->
```

and i know its a formatting issue my css:

```
 .table {display: table;width:600px;position:relative;margin:0 auto;}
.tr {display: table-row;}
.td {display: table-cell;}

.table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:auto;

}
.tr 
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    height:auto;
    width:25%;

}
.th{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size:20px;
    height:40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:25%;

    }


.thead{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size:20px;
    height:40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:25%;

    }


.td{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size:20px;
    height:40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:25%;
    }

.td1{
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    margin:15px; 
    width:25%;
    }
.screenpos{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Can anyone guide where I've gone wrong? I'm new to putting my tables in div's and such.

Comment: ok so it doesnt display it when i type it out either, i want it to have section serial bike time along the top, mine goes down vertically, then the details to display correctly too!

Comment: `<div class="td">` - are you trying to replicate the  `<table>` tag using divs??

Comment: Why would you even want to use divs instead of tables in case like this?

Comment: yes trying to create the table using div's and seeing as tables will soon not work id like to make practice of using div's to make tables.

Comment: `and seeing as tables will soon not work` - what? If you're working with tabular data, then use `<table>`

Comment: table is being deprecated eventually, so id like to learn how to use it in this method.

Comment: No, no it isn't..who told you this..

Comment: HTML5 does not support any of the HTML 4 attributes: align, bgcolor, border, cellpadding, cellspacing, frame, rules, summary, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp so should i go back to using tables? i think i might of misunderstood what was said there..

Comment: table is not an attribute and does not require any of those you listed.

Comment: it's just saying use css to style your tables. your above code does not give display properties to .th or .thead

Comment: The `<table>` tag is still supported, they're talking about `attributes`, and separating styling from the markup. You should use CSS to style up the table ie adding padding, borders etc.

Comment: And by the way HTML5 and XHTML do not support any attribute that should be used for presentation/style . HTML is for contents/semantics, CSS for presentation/style.

Comment: Moreover why do you use php print to print fixed text (the table header with column definitions)???

Comment: ok thanks alot. sorry for the confusion, i have mis understood whats what :)

Comment: Improve also your php code.

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure should be something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Table heading 1</th>
        <th>Table heading 2</th>
        <th>Table heading 3</th>
        <th>Table heading 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez6tq/)**